# CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation change the frame height

Tags: ios, animation, cgaffinetransform

When I try to use the animation, I use CGAffineTransform, but the translation just change the frame size, I can't find the problem. Here is the code:

```
NSLog(@"%.2f", self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
CGAffineTransform scrollViewTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0);
self.scrollView.transform = scrollViewTransform;
NSLog(@"%.2f", self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
```

The frame size changed in log:

```
2015-12-03 21:51:42.455 Travel[12217:1015615] 608.00
2015-12-03 21:51:42.455 Travel[12217:1015615] 672.00
```

The scrollview frame size set in viewDidLayoutSubviews.

Answer (score 0):

Actually problem is not in above code of transform.

Your problem may be in **viewDidLayoutSubviews** because it is called many time.So you have to check your code in **viewDidLayoutSubviews.**

And if you want to use transform to move your content you can use below code for moving object from right to left animation :-

```
yourView.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation((yourView.frame.size.width+yourView.frame.size.width),0);
[UIView transitionWithView:yourView
                          duration:1.0
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                        animations:^{
                            yourView.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,0);
                        }
completion:^(BOOL finished) {
}];
```